# Is there a faster way to return multiple values when looping over function?

Tags: python, physics

```
positions=[];  velocities=[]

for _ in range(1000):   
    position, velocity = generateRandomVectors()
    positions.append(position)
    velocities.append(velocity)
```

Can this be done faster?
For example, appending values at a different stage, or using a different kind of loop?

Current times:

```
n=100
times = timeit.repeat(lambda: test1(), number=n, repeat=10, timer=time.process_time)
print(min(times)/n)  
--- 0.04439204000000018 ---
```

Fast, but I have a lot of vectors to generate.

Comment: If you're looking for speed python is not the right tool...

Comment: Isn't a lot of machine learning done with Python? So are you saying that machine learning doesn't need speed?

Comment: *"0.04439204000000018"* - Strange, for me it only takes about [0.00021](https://tio.run/##dVDBasMwDL37K3S0IWQpYzAy8gs77LDLKMVN1M5Qy0ZWC/36zI4xZYNdJKSnp/ekeJfvQM@vkdfV@RhYQJxHJ92WlVrwBGckZCv4YWkJ/hNnCZy0GRUAo1yZ4D0QdlusDMEkuzoRQ3LiAqXpa/8GcMNLmHMDS60yfgoMB3AEbOmMejcMgxkBIEMPctd4d5j@s/OLkHobI9KiW6PCD/WGt71GKZqyuPrj52U7ovwiZen6m54xohV9sf642LFd2wFd/RF5ynbrRF5Y/8hTiX3kMGNKh1IUQ5EdifaO9CZgnsis6w8), that's over 200 times faster. Very very strange.

Comment: @NirAlfasi I don't know whether or not that's true but regardless, I'm asking this question because I don't have a choice in language.

Comment: @superbrain sure, when you write your module in C/C++ it will run much faster. However, I don't believe this is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @NirAlfasi I need to write C/C++ modules myself? Can't I just use existing ones?

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I love Python, and I didn't invent [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjaf9b4kumhkdeb/python.jpeg?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use vectorization as much as possible

```
def generateRandomVectors():
    return np.random.randn(3), np.random.randn(3)

positions=[];  velocities=[]
for _ in range(1000):   
    position, velocity = generateRandomVectors()
    positions.append(position)
    velocities.append(velocity)
```

2.19 ms ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

If instead of generating one vector per call I generate the 1000 in one call it runs about 15x faster here

```py
def generateRandomVectors(n):
    return np.random.randn(n, 3), np.random.randn(n, 3)

positions, velocities = generateRandomVectors(1000)
```

145 µs ± 533 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

One difference is that now positions and velocities are arrays and not lists. Good because you save memory and can do batched operations, great if you will not try to append more elements.

Comment: How about `np.random.randn(n, 3)` without extra `reshape`?

Comment: Thank you for the observation,  it is difficult to me to remember all the functions receive multidimensional size or only number of element. Since you mentioned I will update.

Comment: Hmm, somewhat disappointing that that didn't make it faster.

Comment: You mean removing the extra reshape? that does not do any difference on speed because it is the same data, only viewed in a different way.

Comment: @user12750353 Thank you very much! My final calculation (more complicated than the example in my question) is about 10x faster when bearing this info in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [`split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy.split) method from the [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) module:

```
from numpy import split, array

position, velocity = split(array(tuple(generateRandomVectors() for _ in range(1000))), 2, 1)
```

If you don't have the `numpy` module, you can [install it](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) via the command prompt command

```
pip install numpy
```